# Android Images Become Blurry In Emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-icons

Alright now this problem might sound funny but I am not here for jokes. However, I use eclipse for android developement, the problem is that whenever i place my icons in the res/drawables 
and run the application in emulator the images in the icons become blurry, this is with out the nine patch. However , when i change the icons to nine patch and then place them, the icons become more blurry i dont understand why. Now you see the best part is that the icons dont appear blurry in an android mobile phone(ldpi screen), i suppose the same will go for the others hdpi and mdpi. Why is this happening ? Is there a problem in the transparency ?Are there some changes need to be done in the xml file? Answers , Tips , advices required please . 
:)

Answer (score 0):

What is the screen density for the emulator? If you are using small images, when you put them in resources they probably become blurry when they get scaled up.

Comment: the emulator i am using has platform of 4.1.2 , density 240.

Comment: What is the size of the image placed in res/drawables? Also please post the size of the image you are displaying (post the xml file where you have the image that is blurry). It would be very well if you would separate your resources in different folders, depending on the screen size, look here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible that the density of the emulator is low due to which your images' size get increased and they get faded. try to align the image size and density according to the density of emulator or device. I solved my problem with this.

Comment: how much should be the density for a good , clear image? . Mine is 240 and platform is 4.1.2.